# Обработать пустую строку в консоли при использовании BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

У меня есть задача где пользователь вводит 3 числа не превосходящих 10^9 по модулю, если все 3 числа четные ,то на экран выводится WIN , в остальных случаях FAIL.И я не могу понять как используя BufferedReader обработать пустую строку и вывести FAIL

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int[] array = new int[3];
    String[] strNums;
    strNums = br.readLine().split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // заполняем массив
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
            if (strNums[i].isEmpty() == true){
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array[0] % 2 == 0 && array[1] % 2 == 0 && array[2] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("WIN");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам столько всего? В Этом коде можно ввести неограниченное количество цифр церез пробел. Если хотите конкретно 3, то добавьте проверку массива на размер. Чтобы сделать еще проще - используйте класс Scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String maychResult = "WIN";
    String [] arr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().split("\\s");
    for (String arg : arr) {
        if (!isEvenNumber(arg)) {
            maychResult = "FAIL";
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maychResult);
}

private static boolean isEvenNumber(String arg) {
    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(arg.trim()) % 2 == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```